# Installing the newest version of Zabbix Agent on Windows Server

Tags: service, uninstallation, zabbix, file-not-found

I've got a problem in installing the newest version of Zabbix agent on Windows Server via vm boxes in Linux, since the old version of zabbix has not been uninstalled perfectly. Zabbix agent service is existed however the system cannot file the file related to specified address in services.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the Windows service:

```
zabbix_agentd.exe --config c:\zabbix_agentd.conf --uninstall
```

You might also want to use the `zabbix_agentd.win.conf` example file, if the config file isn't a copy of that one already.

Comment: I had tried this command all the time but I've got an error in each time.This time I have downloaded the bin and config file from the internet and put this in the path of missing file that the windows services couldn't find then run this command <Path_zabbix.exe> -c <Path_zabbix.conf> -d. and Install the newest version properly.